# Prevent cell name to be written in the cell when zoomed out

Tags: excel

If I assign a name to a big merged cell (5+ by 5+), and zoom out, the name of the cell is written inside it. Not the cell's value, the actual NAME. You can try it yourself. Why would that be useful? How can I prevent it?

[image]

Comment: It only happens when the zoom is 10% or 25% and it actually writes it over what is written in the cell. It makes it hard to read anything....

Comment: This is probably just a gray watermark that will not be visible when printing the spreat sheet. Why does it bother you? Please be more specific in your question.

Comment: @AlphSpirit did you try it? It's not about printing my spreadsheet. I have a big work process in a sheet and have to zoom out to see it all, but then the cell's names get written all over and I can't read. It is not a grey watermark, it is very much blue text.

Comment: As I said, be more specific. Include a screenshot of what you're talking about, tell us which version of Excel you are running and more detailed steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Relevant: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/119051-dont-display-range-name-when-zooming.html

Comment: @AlphSpirit I reckon you did not try it yourself, because I was specific enough. That is really all there is to it. By zooming out, the cell's assigned name gets written inside it. If I zoom in it disappears. There is no value in the example I shown, but it does it even when the cell has text inside and covers it. This is an extremely large cell to show a clear example, but it happens with smaller ones too. Excel 2010. Steps to reproduce: Merge a big cell. Assign a name. Zoom out until name appears. Pic related (answer edited).

Comment: @AlphSpirit  Well, that's a disappointing conclusion. Thanks for your time.